# Angular2: Update navbar data?

Tags: angular

I would like to have some direction as to how to accomplish the following:

I have two separate components: `navbar` and `homepage`.

In the navbar I have a placeholder for `city name`.

In the home page I have  a form component of which one is a city field. Depending on the city I choose on the form I would like to update the navbar with the city name.

Can someone let me know how I can solve this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: It would be a shared service. Check this, says it's for parent and child, but works as well between other components: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Have a wrapper component and share the data
2. Use a shared service.

I suggest you first option, because it is neat design.

First option example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/EDrQsxxCeCVhXoQcra4i?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <mynavbar [navbarData] = "commonData"> </mynavbar>
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>

    <somecomponent [someComponentData]="commonData"> </somecomponent>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  commonData;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
    this.commonData = { cityName: 'SpringField' };
  }
}
```

Second option example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Xob4jNuIX0DtvGj5gtIx?p=preview

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService{
  commonData;
  constructor(){
     this.commonData = { cityName: 'SpringField' };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you omeralper, this solution works for me. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is either an Output or Input. The below assumes navbar is within the homepage component but the concept would apply regardless of your particular setup. If reverse just swap it out with an output from component to navbar, or put the input in the parent component.

homepage component

```
@Component({
  template: `<my-navbar [city]="city"></my-navbar>
             <form>
               <input [(ngModel)]="city"></input>
             </form>`
 })
 export class HomePageComponent {
     public city;
 }
```

and the navbar component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-navbar',
    template: `<p>{{city}}</p>
)}
export class NavbarComponent {
  @Input city;
}
```

in this example whenever you change the city input inside your home component, the element in the navbar will also be updated in realtime.

Comment: Joshua, no, my navbar component is not within my home page component. The two component are completely separate. I need to know how to pass the value to the navbar in this situation.

Comment: Please provide a plunkr in that case so I can see what you're going for and I'll be happy to help.